# How to check if element exists xmlt -> html

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a question:

I have a xml file like this:

```
<tag1>
    <tag2>
        <tag3 property="bag"/>
        <tag3 property="charger"/>
    </tag2>
</tag1>
```

And i would like to do following if tag3 exists under tag2 print out one thing, else say no tags found.
i have tried so far this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/tag1/tag2>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="??">
            I HAVE A TAG3
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            I DONT HAVE A TAG3
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I am wondering what to do in the place i have '??'

Best Regards,
Egert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to test for an existence of an element, then simply use the element name

```
<xsl:for-each select="/tag1/tag2>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="tag3">
        I HAVE A TAG3
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        I DONT HAVE A TAG3
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Alternatively, use a templated approach

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="tag1/tag2" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag2[tag3]">
    I have tag 3
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag2">
    I do not have tag 3
</xsl:template>
```

In this case, the template matching `tag2` with the extra condition has higher priority than the other one. This means the second template will only match `tag2` elements which don't have  `tag3` under them.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't even know it was that easy!